# What do I do when SE sites are dysfunctional and legitimate questions get terminated no matter what?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, close-reasons

First, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801774/wtf-moments-in-python-closed), which immediately got shut down for being *ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form*.
Some guy there told me that "it need[ed] rewording."

OK. So I reworded the question so that it could be taken as less ambiguous. The
end result was [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802265/what-are-the-python-features-you-found-unintuitive-or-surprising-closed) covering essentially the same content.

Again, it didn't last for a minute.

Kind people on both of these links had been advising me that this sort of
question would be more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com.

For the second time, I followed their advice and asked it on
[programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/wtf-moments-in-python-programming-closed).

Again, the question got beaten up and died in a short period of time.

I'm nowhere.
No matter what I do with "your" advice, people vote for closing it.
What do I do in this case?

Comment: Realize that your question wasn't meant for Stack Overflow. Also, change your gravatar to a Unicorn and mutter something about waffles.

Comment: @George That's why I asked it on programmers SE.

Comment: @OTZ, given that they're trying to clean up Programmers.SE, maybe your question isn't meant for there, either? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65439/should-developer-testing-be-folded-into-a-more-general-programmers-site/65618#65618

Comment: @George then where is it meant to be?

Comment: @OTZ: it's certainly possible that it's not meant to be *anywhere*. StackExchange doesn't guarantee you an answer to every question.

Comment: As an aside: when a question is closed for some reason, why not edit THAT VERY question to see if it's reopened? Posting the same in a new question does not help keeping the sites clean.

Comment: @Michael I'd be surprised if anyone thinks the opposite. What you are saying is merely a truism. please be more substantive.

Comment: @OTZ: what more would you like to know?

Comment: The problem is that those questions really really aren't "legitimate"

Comment: @radp Can you elaborate? I can't read your mind.

Comment: I'm rather surprised it got closed on programmers; it seemed like exactly the kind of question they like there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we ask subjective questions - and if so where?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55965/can-we-ask-subjective-questions-and-if-so-where)

Comment: "What answer would you accept?" That's for the audience to decide. It's very useful to remember that **the totality of subjective votes represents objectivity as the number of votes goes to infinity.** I'll just sit back for a while and see what they have to say/vote.

Comment: @OTZ: `...and see what they have to say/vote.` And they have spoken, period. *No insult intended.*

Comment: I still haven't understood if you want __answers__ or you want a __popularity contest__ where people vote on stuff they like, except they hardly ever scroll down much let alone visit page two. And then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/84556/13992) happens.

Comment: @radp:  That's a difference between Stack Overflow and Programmers:  Programmers is for the subjective questions.  There's a thread on its meta about showing the accept rate.  There is, however, such a thing as being too vague, and this seems to have triggered it.

Comment: @David, I'd have to dig into the Programmers' meta to know what their policies are, so I can't speak for that site. Personally, I doubt about Programmers' future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry that acting on my comment didn't save your question. Poll-type questions are generally frowned on, even though some of the early ones have survived just by having been around for long enough.

Concerning Programmers.se, you were probably just a victim of bad timing, as George Stocker linked in his comment, they're in the process of trying to do some kind of 'clean up' there too.

Comment: No worries. I certainly appreciate you commenting on this thread. thanks.

Answer (score 16):

StackExchange isn't about everything with a question mark. Subjective questions work poorly here. Such questions attract people views and activity, taking homepage  visibility away from what really SE is about: solving practical problems.

There are eleventy million sites for programmer chit chat, including the upcoming SO chat.

Also, your second question has been closed as duplicate -- why did you just *need* your very own duplicate? At the end of the day, you should be glad the hidden features of (x) questions still are allowed at all to continue existing -- on many SEs they'd be closed just as expeditiously.

Comment: And + 1 for *why did you just need your very own duplicate?*

Answer (score 8):

Well, that is the one that you re-worded into [What are the Python features you found unintuitive or surprising?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802265/what-are-the-python-features-you-found-unintuitive-or-surprising). I think we can all agree that *at most* only one of those two needs to live, and as it happens both are pretty-much directly related to the existing [Hidden Features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python).

So IMO, the answer here is "look to existing questions *first*". When you've read the wisdom in the 147 existing answers, then perhaps is the time to create a *specific*, *answerable* question on the topic.

But the originals (both, or all three if we include [their C cousin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801921/wtf-moments-in-c-programming), with [existing conjoined twin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132241/hidden-features-of-c)) are indeed pretty vague.

Comment: Right. I agree that the second question could be closed for being similar to "Hidden Features of Python". But the question on programmers SE, I believe, should be there to live. Did you read the reason for the close? "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here." Is the intension of "WTF moments in Python" difficult to understand? I don't think so.

Comment: @OTZ - I can't comment on the SE, since I'm not involved. Perhaps seek clarification at [that site's meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/). However, my suspicion is that both communities (and there is a lot of overlap) are finding "list me 235 examples of [x]" bothersome - they don't tend to give hugely *valuable* discussions. Have *you* read the 147 python answers, for example? And I mean all of them, not just the first two.

Comment: I think WTF features are different from hidden features. WTF features are generally more subtle, whereas hidden features are mostly just like other language features once you learn them -- they just don't come up often, though some of them can be subtle like WTF features.

Comment: I didn't know there was a meta site for programmers SE. I thought this meta was also the meta for programmers SE. Thanks for the information. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you

- checked that it wasn't asked before
- thought about the question and its relevance for the SO community
- added some own effort in the form of code, examples and/or links
- really really want to know this and not just suck out a question to get some reputation

then you should edit:NOT mark that kind of questions as a community wiki. If there is no objective answer possible, you shouldn't ask it here.

Comment: Nope. CW is not there to be able to post list or subjective questions. CW is there to allow the community to edit a post and collaboratively contribute to a question. **CW is not an excuse, or way, to get subjective questions to become acceptable.**

Comment: @Diago : see point 2. In the example of the OP, I doubt the question is very subjective. There are quite some questions about quirks/favorite tricks etc. on SO, and I personally learnt a lot from them already. It's a matter of opinion off course, hence my inclusion of point 2.

Comment: There is a reason there is a new programmers SE site. As for past questions having been allowed, the community has changed and therefore it's not allowed. However, you whole answer gives the indication that it is OK if it is CW. **This is not the case**.

Comment: @Diago : could you please give an example of a question that should be community wiki? Not to contradict you, but I can't possible imagine a wiki question without it being at least partly subjective.

Comment: Have you ever read the Community Wiki FAQ, and what the purpose of it is? [What are Community Wiki Posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). Questions are automatically switched to CW after a certain number of edits, among other things. If you actually searched meta for CW you'll find a few posts in which the above point has been made clear numerous times.

Comment: @Diago : yes, I read that before, hence my question. A non-subjective question with a definite answer can't ever enter wiki mode.

Comment: I think you need to read that very carefully. It can. In fact there is a few questions that have already. My point is, **CW is not an excuse or valid way of posting subjective questions.** The FAQ clearly states subjective questions are not allowed, and as much as you want to argue that it is, the community moderators, and diamond moderators will shut these questions down on sight, CW or not. Even more so now that there is a programmers SE site.

Comment: @Joris, CW is great for questions that require a long and intricate list of answers, as long as there are a finite number of answers and they are all objective. I'll look for some examples now.

Comment: @Diago : from one of the discussions : *Conclusion:
A question should not be marked CW if it is possible to write valid, helpful and knowledgeable answers which contribute to SO.* So the only conclusion I can draw then is that no valid questions on SO should be marked CW. - PS : I'm not arguing this, I'm just trying to correct my understanding of CW.

Comment: CW is exactly what the FAQ states. **It allows the community to collaboratively own and maintain the content of a post**. That all it is. There are rules that will force even valid and helpful questions into CW automatically, and it is rare for an author to make a question CW themselves. Which is way you can edit a CW question with only a 100 reputation among other things.

Comment: @Popular Demand : thx for looking, I'm really trying to understand the purpose of CW, as I marked some of my own questions CW based on my -apparently wrong- understanding.

Comment: @Diago : OK, thx for the explanation.

Comment: @Joris, examples: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6149/which-fallout-3-items-are-sought-after-by-npcs/6151#6151 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953 (note that it doesn't _have_ to be for list questions, it's anything that would be better edited by the whole community than just one person... that just usually ends up meaning a list, in practice)

Comment: RE: "no valid questions on SO should be marked CW" - for the most part, CW on questions is rarely necessary. It's best suited to answers, and when it's actually needed for editing. Votes are more important than reputation, and that's what CW preserves. That's why CW is not really a good mechanism against subjective material - we still end up with messed up votes. It's better off for when we want to preserve the quality, but want to open up access. And frankly, valid questions tend to be more personal in their goals than what CW is meant to address.